# Android Studio Gradle Error - preDexDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I recently added a new activity to my android studio project and now I am getting an error when I try and run it. It builds fine but I get the error below when I run it:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/dx --dex --output /Users/davidcavanagh/joshcpdandroid/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-22ecb8c50fefe43948d87c9fee8e36a6b7d1bb5a.jar /Users/davidcavanagh/joshcpdandroid/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/20.0.0/classes.jar
  Error Code:
    1
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.joshcpd.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:zbar')
}
```

I have tried removing the supportLappcompat dependency but then I get even more errors. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to add to dependencies:    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'

Comment: Im afraid that didn't work. I still have the same error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by downloading the latest version of gradle.

I still get this error every so often and I just fix it by going to File ----> Invalidate caches/restart

I find Android Studio to be very buggy

Answer (score 1):

Based on where it's trying to find the dx command:

> /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/dx

it looks like you've crossed a build tools version with something else. The build file you posted in your question looks okay, but look in the other build files in your project (there's at least going to be something in `libraries/zbar`) and make sure their `buildToolsVersion` statements are okay. I suspect somewhere you have:

```
buildToolsVersion 'android-4.4W'
```

where you should have:

```
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
```

Comment: No that didn't work. I think Im either missing a correct dependency or there is a conflict like you said. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now i know the reason of the problem. It was causes by wrong code in `\sdk\android-sdk\tools\lib\find_java.bat`

Wrong code:

```
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64
```

Correct code:

```
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32||set arch_ext=64
```

The wrong code leads to the path of `java_exe` be

```
E:\Android\sdk\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\\find_java32 .exe
```

So, when `dx.bat` runs

```
call "%java_exe%" %javaOpts% -Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%" -jar "%jarpath%" %params%
```

it will report the wrong status:

```
Error Code:
    1
```

My platform: win8-32 bit android studio 1.0 - 4GB RAM

Comment: It is a bug in tools 24

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, so I uninstalled the java jdk and reinstalled the latest version from oracle and everything went OK. The link for installing the latest version of jdk is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Note: you need to update the jdk directory in android studio after doing the above