# React Native fresh build error on compiling to android device

Tags: java, android, react-native

I recently build fresh app using `react-native init`.

After run `react-native run-android` I got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 19.52 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

(node:3632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
(node:3632) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've already tried to run `gradlew clean` inside my android folder but still no luck.

Any solution?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847482/error-gradle-execution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529155/android-studio-gradle-error-predexdebug)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and after a lot of troubleshooting I found out that the android project was corrupted. Here's how I fixed mine:

From project folder:

1. `rm -rf android`
2. `react-native upgrade`

Note: just running react-native upgrade without deleting the android folder does not seem to work.