# i tried running my react native project using react-native run-android command : my emulator is well set up. Please what is wrong

Tags: react-native

```
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0392Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug FAILED
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

  > org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/Certificate
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 31.39 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

> (node:9816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection >>(rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
>   (node:9816) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: BUILD FAILED app: PackageDebug error..

Comment: the output states that a promise rejection is unhandled.. which means that you are calling a promise without a catch function. Do you have any promises without catch?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check out my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438529/react-native-fresh-build-error-on-compiling-to-android-device/41840034#41840034

Answer (score 0):

Search for your gradle folder and delete its content, then run react-native run again. It is due to version difference(provided every other thing is OK).